# Splitting a Quadratic into to separate quadratics.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

$$\begin{align}\pi(\mu,\sigma^2|x)&\propto\sigma^{-(n+2)}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2\right)\\
&=\sigma^{-(n+2)}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x)^2 + n(\bar x -\mu)^2\right]\right)\\ 
&=\sigma^{-(n+2)}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left[(n-1)s^2+ n(\bar x -\mu)^2\right]\right)\end{align} $$

I am just wondering if this is just a unique scenario, I am struggling from getting to the first line to the second line and I feel as if this explanation is really lacking some details, so I assume that this sort of trick is somewhat very common?

Comment: Yes.  Changing "variance of the sample relative to the population mean" (so mixing two things that don't mix well) into "variance of the sample" and "constant, dependent on sample size and difference of means" is mentally useful because it sorts apples from oranges.  Also, the rewrite $a - b \mapsto a - c + c - b$ in order to break up $|a-b|$ or $(a-b)^2$ (see triangle inequality) into pieces that are separately easier is fairly common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming here that $\bar x $ and $s^2$ respectively denote the sample mean and sample variance, i.e.

$$\bar x := \frac1 n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ \text{ and } \ s^2:=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x)^2$$

The detailed steps of the computation are the following :

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x + \bar x -\mu)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left((x_i -\bar x) + (\bar x -\mu)\right)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left[(x_i -\bar x)^2 + (\bar x -\mu)^2 + 2(x_i -\bar x)(\bar x -\mu)\right] \tag1 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left[(x_i -\bar x)^2 + (\bar x -\mu)^2\right] +\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ 2(x_i -\bar x)(\bar x -\mu)\right] \tag2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x)^2 + n(\bar x -\mu)^2 +2(\bar x -\mu)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x) \tag3 \end{align}$$
Where in $(1)$ we used the $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab $ identity, in $(2)$ we used the linearity of the sum and in $(3)$ we used the fact that $\bar x$ and $\mu$ do not depend on $i$.
All that's left is to show that that extra $2(\bar x -\mu)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x) $ term is equal to zero, but it indeed is because
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i -\bar x)  &= \sum_{i=1}^nx_i -n\bar x\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n n\frac{x_i}{n} -n\bar x \\
&= n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{n} -n\bar x\\
&= n\bar x - n \bar x = 0 \end{align}$$
So that's the detailed explanation of how you go from the first to the second line. As for your question, as said in Eric Towers' comment, it is indeed a fairly common technique to add and retract the $\bar x$ term to obtain expressions where terms that are function of the sample points $x_i$ (like here the sample variance) are separated from terms that depend on the distribution (here the difference between sample and true mean).